# Build kernel in one machine, install in another

Tags: kernel, compiling, kernel-modules

I want to build my Linux kernel on my host and use it in my VWware virtual machine. They both use the same Ubuntu kernel now.

On my Host, I do `make` and `make configure`. Then, what files should I copy to the target machine, before I do `make modules_install` and `make install`?

What other things do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'best' way to do this, is building it as a package. You can then distribute and install it to any Ubuntu machine running the same (major) version.

For building vanilla kernels from source, there's a tool `make-kpkg` which can build the kernel as packages. Other major advantages: easy reverting by just removing the package, automatic triggers by the package management such as rebuilding DKMS, etc.

The Ubuntu community wiki on [Kernel/Compile Alternate Build Method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile#Alternate_Build_Method%3a_The_Old-Fashioned_Debian_Way) provides a few steps on how to do that.

Basically, it's just the same as building the kernel from upstream documentation, but instead of having `make` blindly installing it on your system, have it build in a 'fake root' environment and make a package out of it, using

```
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-some-string-here \
  kernel-image kernel-headers
```

This should produce binary `.deb` files which you will be able to transfer to other machines and install it using

```
dpkg -i mykernelfile-image.deb mykernelfile-headers.deb ...
```

Answer (score 6):

I would comment on gertvdijk's answer but I don't have enough rep to comment.

I don't know if any of that is necessary now that rpm-pkg, deb-pkg, snap-pkg are viable targets for make.

So with Ubuntu, I'd imagine you'd like to use

```
make bindeb-pkg
```

(use `make deb-pkg` if you need to include source)

on RPM distros (RHEL, Fedora, CentOS) you'd use rpm-pkg/binrpm-pkg

see the Kernel Packaging section of `make help` for all options

```
Kernel packaging:
    rpm-pkg             - Build both source and binary RPM kernel packages
    binrpm-pkg          - Build only the binary kernel RPM package
    deb-pkg             - Build both source and binary deb kernel packages
    bindeb-pkg          - Build only the binary kernel deb package
    snap-pkg            - Build only the binary kernel snap package (will connect to external hosts)
    tar-pkg             - Build the kernel as an uncompressed tarball
    targz-pkg           - Build the kernel as a gzip compressed tarball
    tarbz2-pkg          - Build the kernel as a bzip2 compressed tarball
    tarxz-pkg           - Build the kernel as a xz compressed tarball
    perf-tar-src-pkg    - Build perf-5.2.0.tar source tarball
    perf-targz-src-pkg  - Build perf-5.2.0.tar.gz source tarball
    perf-tarbz2-src-pkg - Build perf-5.2.0.tar.bz2 source tarball
    perf-tarxz-src-pkg  - Build perf-5.2.0.tar.xz source tarball
```