Install TP-Link Archer T2U V3 driver in Linux without Internet
I'm using an Archer T2U v3 on my Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 system and on a Linux Mint system based on these Ubuntu versions. It works flawlessly with the driver directly provided by TP-Link from their website (with kernel version 2.6.18~5.0).
Following the installation guide, I just had to run make to compile their driver and load it using sudo insmod 88x2bu.ko.
Recently I upgraded my system and found that the make command doesn't work from Ubuntu 18.04 onward; it says make should be installed first.
So I did some research and have already gone through these links:

TP-Link AC600 Archer T2U Nano driver for Ubuntu 18.04
Need rtl8814au driver for kernel 5.3 on Ubuntu 19.10
Archer T2U Plus driver for Linux Ubuntu/Rasbian
RTL8812AU/21AU and RTL8814AU Wireless drivers for Linux

According to these I'll have to execute these commands:
sudo apt install git dkms 
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git 
cd rtl8812au 
sudo make dkms_install

There is a problem: I cannot access the Internet directly on this PC even through USB tethering (mobile is not allowed in the workplace). Can I somehow install these packages (dkms, git, build-essential, linux-headers) from another working machine on this machine? Can I install those packages in offline mode?

Check this out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59257/build-kernel-in-one-machine-install-in-another . DKMS is not necessary, but to be able to make the kernel module from git repo you linked would still need a lot of packages to be manually installed with dpkg -i. So instead try to package that module into a .deb and install. But I think you should just ask the admins to do it for you, they could plug a usb NIC and get done with it. If you must, dive into packaging software for deployment, so less work now and in future.

@cbugk thanks for replying actually I'm admin in this case and I don't have access to internet to this PC without wifi adapter so I'm trying this much to get a proper solution

You could use sudo apt-get install --download-only on the other machine and copy over the .deb files. You could also cross compile the driver on the working machine and copy over the .ko file if you want to avoid installing a lot of packages on the target machine.

My fellow admin, then definitely find a way to get it into a package then, and archive the scripts and package. I had tried installing 2.5G Realtek 8125 drivers offline, and had to resort to using a USB ethernet because any package I tried to install manually to have a compilation ready would ask for even more packages. Unless you want to become the package manager itself, follow the rabbit hole above (just found after your question, might not be the real deal). Oh, would appreciate if you could write an answer for future reference. Godspeed!

If the working machine has internet, maybe the simplest solution is to share internet using a ethernet cable: https://askubuntu.com/a/194526

Why not buy a well supported card and put it in the machine?

I answered this on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1514031/install-tp-link-archer-t2u-v3-driver-in-ubuntu-without-internet/1514047#1514047

I’m voting to close this question because I answered this on AskUbuntu: askubuntu.com/questions/1514031/… –
waltinator
